# MATLAB if statement contains string value extract number and do a math operation

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to take a users input as a string value and then use an if statement to verify if string contains particular letter. Then extract the numbers from the string and do a math operation. Its temperature conversion program i'm working on for school. Its incomplete but im just trying to get the above to work before filling in the rest. I'm new at this so any advice helps.

the error code im getting

*Error using contains
Not enough input arguments.

Error in program2taylor (line 16)
if str == contains(pattern1) %converting from C`*

```
pattern1 = 'C' || 'c';
pattern2 = 'F' || 'f';

str = input('Enter number and letter EX: 56F, 67C' , 's');

if str == contains(pattern1) %converting from C
    
    str(isstrprop(str, 'digit'))

    str = str - 1;

    fprintf("%s" , str );

end
```

Comment: Error is pretty clear. Have you looked at the documentation for [`contains`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/string.contains.html)?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add breakpoints and debug your code.

Using this:

```
pattern1 = 'C' || 'c';
```

Will just output `pattern1 = true`, likely what you actually want is

```
if contains( str, 'c', 'ignorecase', true )
```

Or equivalently,

```
if contains( str, {'C', 'c'} )
```

Then to actually extract the number from a string like `52F` you can erase the `F` or `C` and then use `str2double`

```
pattern1 = {'C', 'c'};
if contains( str, pattern1 )
    str = erase( str, pattern1 ); % remove C/c
    temp = str2double( str );     % convert from char to number
end
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you first need to make a `pattern` (https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/pattern.html), and then use the correct syntax for `contains`.

```
contains('Cheese', caseInsensitivePattern('c'))
```